# Call to a member function update() on null Laravel function

Tags: php, laravel, function, frameworks

What is wrong with this function? I ve got error on this line:
`$user->update($input);` Call to a member function update() on null

```
$input = $request->all();

if ($input == NULL) {
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}

else {
    
    $user = User::find($id);
    
    $user->update($input);
    
    DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $id)->delete();
    
    $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));
    
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
        ->with('success', 'User updated successfully');
    
}
```

Comment: Clearly it couldn't find a user with that ID. You can use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()` to do a 404 if it couldn't find it.

Comment: As the error tells you, you are calling `->update` on a null object, so `$user` is null, and so `User::find($id);` returns `null`, and so there is no user with `id = $id`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if user has some data. Or you can `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`.

```
$input = $request->all();

if ($input == NULL) {
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}

else {
    
    $user = User::find($id);
    if ($user) {
        $user->update($input);
        
        DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', $id)->delete();
        
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('users.index')
        ->with('success', 'User updated successfully');
    
}
```